# "dotnet build" fails: "Solution file error MSB4249: Unable to build website project"

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-cli

Besides .net core 2.2 projects, my solution file contains a website project. When I am in Visual Studio and I run "Rebuild Solution" everything builds successfully, including the website.

In the build output, I see:

```
>Validating Web Site
9>Building directory '/e2e/'.
9>Building directory '/node_modules/.bin/'.
... etc ...
```

But it I try to run "dotnet build" (v3.1.200) from the folder containing the solution file, it fails with this error:

```
Solution file error MSB4249: Unable to build website project "ClientApp". The ASP.NET compiler is only available on the .NET
Framework version of MSBuild
```

How can I build my solution from the command line?

[Does Visual Studio run "dotnet build" to build the solution"? If so, with what arguments?]

Comment: You can only use MSBuild to build such a solution. `dotnet` CLI requires a solution with pure SDK style projects.

Comment: @LexLi Msbuild does try to build the website project. But it fails for a different reason: "... \node_modules\selenium
-webdriver\lib\test\data\web.config(29): error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level." I'm running the command in a "Dev PS Shell VS2019" window. I guess when VS calls msbuild, it's calling it somewhat differently?

Comment: That MSBuild related error indicates misconfiguration on IIS/IIS Express. The message itself "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level" is crystal clear.

Comment: But nothing is mis-configured, since "Build Solution" works fine in VS with no errors. Running msbuild from the command line appears to process the internal code in node_modules, which VS, by default, does not do.

Comment: I can get around this other problem by making node_modules a hidden folder. I guess I can worry some other time about why VS works and msbuild does not, when it is not hidden

Comment: msbuild does other weird things, like build a "Precompiled Web" folder in the solution folder. I would much prefer if there was a way to use"dotnet build" (or even msbuild if necessary) and tell it to ignore the website project.